# How to Get Substring of @FNAME in forfiles command

Tags: variables, batch-file, substring

I want to rename a bunch of files in a directory by stripping their file names down to the first 16 characters but I cannot work out how to get a substring of @FNAME when using the forfiles command in a batch file.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `forfiles` to do this is most likely going to be quite tricky, as I don't think you can set and use variables in the same batch, because you spawn a new cmd for each file (`"cmd /c command"`).

However, the same functionality can easily be achieved using a simple `for` loop.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir C:\yourdir /s /b') do (
set file=%%~na
set ext=%%~xa
set new=!file:~0,16!
ren %%a !new!!ext!
)
```

That will recurse through all subdirectories as well. If you just want the folder you choose, remove the `/s` from the `dir` command.

Also, because you are stripping just the file name, I have made it so it will append the file extension back on after, otherwise the characters in the extension would count towards the 16 character limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a second bat file and pass `@fname` like `%1` and make the substring here.

```
Forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c call second.bat @fname"

In second.bat

Set v=%1

Set substring=%v:~1,5%

Echo %substring%
```